# JavaScript: how to resize div proportionally according to image and parent width?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

I'm developing an application with ReactJS. I have a `content editable div` where the user can add pictures and write text on those pictures. In order to do so when the user adds a picture I append another content editable div to the main content editable and set the background to the picture he selected. This a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

(Note: still trying to figure out why I get that extra margin on the right, it doesn't happen with all pictures; I suppose it has something to do with proportions, rounding and conversion from 100% to pixels. Check the code below.) --> edit: this issue was caused by the border 1px of the div. I fixed it by removing 2px from the image width.

To resize the div and make it of the right size I add a hidden image tag where I load the picture, and on `onload` retrieve the height and width and set my div size accordingly, as follows:

```
// here I create the div that will have the background image

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image.webformatURL + ')';
div.style.backgroundSize = 'contain';
div.classList.add('text-page');

// here I create the image tag that will be invisible
// the css tells the image to have width: 100%, hence
// the picture will grow to fit the width

let img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = image.webformatURL;
img.classList.add('editor-thumb');

// here I add the image to the div

div.appendChild(img);

// here I append the div to the main content editable with id 'editor'

document.getElementById('editor').appendChild(div);

img.onload = () => {

    // once the image has loaded I set the div height and width

    // I believe that somehow this is where I get the extra margin mentioned above

    div.style.height = img.height + 'px';

    // fixing the extra margin here below

    div.style.width = (parseInt(img.width) - 2) + 'px';

    // then I get rid of the picture used to get height and width

    div.removeChild(img);
};
```

The css:

```
.text-page {
    background-size: contain;
    text-shadow: 0.075em 0.08em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 90%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.editor-thumb, .text-page {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
}
```

**This is working, but I'm wondering if there's a better / cleaner way to do it.** Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the margin on the right which you mention is the space taken by the scroll bar - to confirm, do `overflow-y:hidden` and see that `width:100%` should be able to cover the whole width of the screen

Comment: The problem happens even with overflow-y: hidden. Anyway I figured out the problem: the div had border 1px, so removing 2 px from the image width solved the issue. Check my main post for the solution.